# How To Display UTF8 In Netbeans 7?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, utf

In my java project, I need to use Arabic text and strings, but the text becomes like `"???????"` , so what wrong ? and how to resolve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can setup your Netbeans with startup option
place it inside `netbeans.conf` into `netbeans_default_options`

`-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

In the end it should look like

`netbeans_default_options="..... -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Hope it'll help you

Comment: I need to add Farsi/Arabic/rtl comment but ver bad position how to fix it? it work properly in eclipse

Comment: I think you have to create whole document (source code file) in rtl/Farsi/Arabic, you cannot mark just one place to be RTL.

Comment: How to create whole document (source code file) in rtl/Farsi/Arabic ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. I wouldn't mix code (LTR) with comments or user texts (RTL). If you can place the comments outside of box to some separate text file and link to it.

Comment: isn't there a regular place in netbeans (7.x) options to say: Dude, assume/default to UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are instructions for setting the default character set in Netbeans to UTF-8 (in Windows):

```
1 Go to C:\Program Files\netbeans-x.x\etc
2 Open netbeans.conf in Notepad.
3 On the netbeans_default_options add: -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. (make sure to put it within the quotation marks)
4 Project properties -> Build -> Compiling ->

    Additional compiler options) text box.- add: -encoding UTF-8 

5 You can also check to make sure that you have increased the memory allocation for Netbeans by looking at the netbeans_default_options line. The default max is 128MB. We have increased this to 256MB.
```

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu go directory 
ex.

> sudo gedit /usr/local/netbeans-8.0/etc/netbeans.conf

Add

> netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Save Fin

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the bellow issue to solve the how to UTF 8 Dari, Pashto, Persian and Arabic Support in Netbeans

1. open the C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc PAT form windows
2. than copy the netbeans.conf into your some place in your computer
3. add the -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 inside netbeans_default_options=
4. like bellow code
5. netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-   XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
6. than replace the file into C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc
7. now close the netbeans and reopen it, so it work all language like Dari, Pashto, Persian, Arabic and etc...