# How to localize Java Calendar class?

Tags: java, date, datetime, localization, calendar

Is it possible to localize Java calendar class to convert current system date to for example Jalali (Persian) date?

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378764/is-there-any-library-or-algorithm-for-persian-shamsi-or-jalali-calendar-in-and) may help you

Comment: you can use https://github.com/razeghi71/JalaliCalendar as an alternative.

Comment: See related Question: [How to implement Persian Calandar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39357121/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create instance you pass the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), for example

```
Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: While the new API is better, You did not support "Terribly troublesome" with some valid proofs :)

Answer (score 1):

## Localize

> How to localize Java Calendar class?

You don’t. Instead, you localize a `ZonedDateTime` object.

The terrible `Calendar` class, actually `GregorianCalendar`, was supplanted years by the `ZonedDateTime` class. All the awful old date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`, etc.) were all outmoded by the modern *java.time* classes.

You can easily convert from the legacy classes to the modern by calling new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar ).toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Now let `DateTimeFormatter` automatically localize while generating a `String` representing textually the date-time value.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( l ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

## Jalali calendar

> convert current system date to for example [Jalali (Persian) date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar)?

Java does come bundled with an implementation of [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) for the Hijrah calendar system: [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html). Perhaps that might meet your needs (I know next-to-nothing about chronologies other than [ISO 8601](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html)).

You might learn more about this by [searching Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20HijrahChronology%20java&t=osx&ia=web).

If that implementation does not meet your needs, you might find one elsewhere or develop your own. Besides the several open-source chronologies bundled with Java, you will find [several more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html) in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, all open-source. You might find others from other sources.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).