# how to use two different calendar in php and sql?

Tags: php, sql, timestamp, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I'm gonna put two different time calendars on registration page, for example something like this:

**Your Gregorian Birthday:**

**Your Jalali BirthDay:**

I already have Georgian Calendar format on my registration page and working well. but I'm totally zero with Jalali Calendar and I don't know how to use it.

For example:

**Georgian Calendar example on my site:**

Birth Day:  1970-11-12 , user age will show automatically Age: 44

How to use second calendar on registration page, something like this:

Jalali calendar example:

Birth Day:  1349-08-21 , and Age: 44

I mean, It will show both calendars on user interface.

I just found these options but I don't know how to use them.

[PersianDate.java](https://github.com/SamiraElhami/persian-calendar/blob/master/PersianCalendar/src/com/smilehightech/PersianDate.java) , [JalaliCalendar](https://github.com/amirmehdizadeh/JalaliCalendar) , and [timeStamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385434/a-good-date-converter-for-jalali-calendar-in-java)

Actually I'm totaly zero, and I don't know how to use it, please guide me how to use it step by step, I mean very basic that I'll understand it and follow it.

Thank you so much

Comment: You need to normalize a date value to one of the calendar. And you could remember a calendar type in another variable (PHP) or row field (SQL). When you need to display it back, you need to check saved calendar type to convert and format the date properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please check this and answer it how to solve it, I really appreciate for your help and time.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333811/change-server-local-calendar-date-to-another-local-calendar-date-using-php