# How to get week of year and week of month in Jalali (Shamsi) calendar

Tags: java

I need to get the week of year and week of the month in Jalali (Shamsi) calendar. Is there a library or snippet of code to do that?

I used JalaliCalendar, but it only has the week of the year

```
System.out.println(JalaliCalendar.weekOfYear(32,1397));
```

I want to have the week of the month too.

**Update:**

I use below library:
https://github.com/razeghi71/JalaliCalendar/

Comment: What is your `JalaliCalender` library address? There are plenty of them on Github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A good date converter for Jalali Calendar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385434/a-good-date-converter-for-jalali-calendar-in-java)

Comment: @oleg.cherednik : it's not. I want to get a specific feature, not just a date convertor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you `com.ibm.icu`. It contains an awesome library for Jalali calendar.

If your project is a maven based, you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>59.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is a sample use of Persian calendar:

```
//configuration
ULocale locale = new ULocale("@calendar=persian");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(7); //Make Saturdays first day of the week.

//usage
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int weekOfYear = (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR_WOY) == year)? calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) : 53;
int weekOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

It is **important** to know `Calendar` and `ULocale` are from `com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar` and `com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale`. **NOT** `java.util`.

If you have any problem in understanding the code, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about kotlin. Could you please provide Java codes?

Comment: @MohammadJavadi Code changed to java.

Comment: Is startOfMonth and startOfWek available in this library?

Comment: @zohreh Of course. The documentation is available [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html).