# Get all Weekend in given month with Jalali Calendar in Java

Tags: java, java-calendar

i´m trying to get the Date of Weekends in given month with Jalali Calendar.but i doesnt work.
i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272519/11144314) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23386074/11144314) solution to solve it but i get same result when i change the month

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ULocale locale = new ULocale("@calendar=persian");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
        cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(7); //Make Saturdays first day of the week.
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,1398);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);


        do {
            // get the day of the week for the current day
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            // check if it is a Saturday or Sunday
            if (day == Calendar.FRIDAY) {//Friday is Weekend in Jalali Calendar

                System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            // advance to the next day
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 10);




    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: These classes are legacy. They've been replaced by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: could you suggest what should i do now? @EdwardKarak

Comment: A very sympathetic suggestion, @EdwardKarak, but I don’t think java.time supports that Jalali calendar, does it?