# Convert Jalali calendar to Georgian in java

Tags: java, date, converters

I am using the class [shown in this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968568/is-there-any-library-or-algorithm-to-convert-shamsijalali-to-gregorian-date-in?answertab=active#tab-top) to convert [Jalali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar) (shamsi) date to Georgian.

And with the below command, I turn the Hijri date into Georgian

```
Date dt = JalaliCalendar.getGregorianDate("1397/01/14");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dt.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I want to display the result as follows : 2018/04/03

Comment: About terminology: You say "Hijri" and probably mean "Solar Hijri" (= Jalali), and then you accept an answer of B. Bourke who understands "Hijri" as the lunar Hijri calendar (of Saudi-Arabia?!) and gives you no solution at all but just says: "Implement it yourself". IMHO a total misunderstanding in the communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat:** I know nothing about either [Jalali calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar) nor [Hijri calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) except for two minutes spent scanning the Wikipedia pages. But I might be able to help you get part way to a solution.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes come bundled with a [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) implementation of [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html).

### Suggestion: Implement `java.time.chrono.Chronology`

I do not see any implementation of [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) for the Jalali calendar either bundled with *java.time* nor in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that does [provide other chronologies](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html).

I imagine it might be ideal if someone did contribute such an implementation. Perhaps such an implementation could be written by following the example of the [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) bundled with Java.

- [`HijrahChronology.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.java)
- [`HijrahDate.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.java)
- [`HijrahEra.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/chrono/HijrahEra.java)
- [`hijrah-config-islamic-umalqura.properties`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/chrono/hijrah-config-islamic-umalqura.properties)

### Hijri (not Jalali)

Here is my ignorant attempt at using the `HijrahDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018, Month.APRIL , 3 ) ;  // Western calendar, defined in `IsoChronology` class:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html
HijrahDate hd = HijrahDate.from( ld  );  // Using class java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-04-03
>
> hd.toString(): Hijrah-umalqura AH 1439-07-17

That seems to be correct for Hijri Calendar as shown on this [Iranian Calendar Converter](http://www.iranchamber.com/calendar/converter/iranian_calendar_converter.php) page.

[image: screenshot of Iranian calendar converter for 2018-04-03 converting to both Jalali & Hijri]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Using my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (or Time4A on Android) enables following short solution out of the box:

```
String input = "1397/01/14";
PersianCalendar jalali =
    ChronoFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, PersianCalendar.axis())
        .parse(input);
PlainDate gregorian = jalali.transform(PlainDate.axis());
String iso8601 = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_DATE.format(gregorian);
System.out.println(iso8601); // 2018-04-03
```

No need to implement your own calendar chronology (which is generally a complex task). If you want to get the result with slashes instead of ISO-format then just use another formatter by:

```
String output = ChronoFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, PlainDate.axis())
        .format(gregorian);
```

### Update for question in comment:

If the input contains a time part then the whole thing is rather a timestamp and not a calendar date. So users can parse to a moment instead.

```
TZID tzid = () -> "Asia/Tehran"; // used as default time zone for parsing
ChronoFormatter<Moment> f =
  ChronoFormatter.setUpWithOverride(Locale.ENGLISH, PersianCalendar.axis())
    .addPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm[:ss]", PatternType.CLDR) // optional seconds
    .build()
    .withTimezone(tzid);
Moment expected =
  PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 4, 3, 10, 15, 5).inTimezone(tzid);
assertThat(
  f.parse("1397/01/14 10:15:05"),
  is(expected));
```

The parsed moment can be converted back to Persian calendar this way:

```
assertThat(
  expected.toGeneralTimestamp(PersianCalendar.axis(), tzid, StartOfDay.MIDNIGHT).toDate(),
  is(PersianCalendar.of(1397, 1, 14)));
```

Comment: if String input = "1397/01/14 10:15:05" then ?

Comment: @ShayanMirzaee I have extended my post as answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use SimpleDateFormatter as follows:

```
    DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat( "YYYY/MM/dd" );
    String formattedDate = df.format(dt);
```

Comment: Formatting patterns are case-sensitive. `YYYY` uppercase means week-based year rather than calendar-year.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Apart from that, the question was about conversion, and the answer hardly addresses that.

Comment: Leaving aside the wrong pattern, its main error is the fact that the Jalali calendar is not supported at all by `SimpleDateFormat`.