# How to convert Date in Android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-json, android-date

I want show date into my application, and i receive this data from server with below json :

```
"date": "2016-08-01 19:55:16"
```

and i set into `textview` with below code :

```
((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));
```

I want convert this date to **jalali/shamsi** . but i don't know how to convert this date and set into `textview` !

Can you help me for this issue?

Comment: if you want to convert the date to  **jalali/shamsi** here is method to convert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378764/is-there-any-library-or-algorithm-for-persian-shamsi-or-jalali-calendar-in-and     and this library  https://github.com/amirmehdizadeh/JalaliCalendar if still there is problem kindly comment

Comment: @FahadRehman, thank you. I copy class in my project, but how can I use this into `((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));` ? please help me, I am amateur and I really need this

Comment: ok i havent tried this library let me try it and i will answer you in few minutes

Comment: @FahadRehman, thanks I am waiting

Comment: @FahadRehman, can you help me my friend?

Comment: I have added the answer if you have any problems let me know, i don't have any idea about Jalali calendar so i cant tell you accuracy about the library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122619/discussion-between-fahad-rehman-and-user6761472).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this https://github.com/amirmehdizadeh/JalaliCalendar to get the Jalali date

first get the year, month and day from your date like

```
String date = "2016-08-01 19:55:16";

String[] parts = date.split(" ");
String datePart = parts[0];
String timePart = parts[1];

int year;
int month;
int day;

String[] dateParts = datePart.split("-");
year = Integer.parseInt( dateParts[0]);
month = Integer.parseInt( dateParts[1]);
day = Integer.parseInt( dateParts[2]);
```

then create the Object to pass to that library

```
JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate  georgianDate = new JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate(year,month,day);
```

and then call its method that convert from Georgian date to Jalali Date

```
 JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate JalaliDate = JalaliCalendar.gregorianToJalali(georgianDate);
```

And Finally append the date with time to show in text view

```
String jalaliDateTime =  JalaliDate.toString() + " " + timePart;
textView.setText(jalaliDateTime);
```

Comment: Hi again FAHAD, are you here? please answer me