# Use android.icu.util.Calendar for API >=24 and java.util.Calendar for API <24

Tags: java, android, calendar, deprecated, icu

As a new Calendar class was introduced in API 24 in package `android.icu.util` with more calendars and better localization.
I'm wondering if there is a way to use this Calendar for Android API >=24, and old deprecated Calendar from `java.util` package for Android API <24.

There is a little reason to set `minSdkVersion = 24`.
Also I cannot assign `android.icu.util.Calendar` to `java.util.Calendar` field depending on API level.
Have anyone solved this? Or just use old calendar and wait untill market drop of old devices?

Comment: Why not take the step and add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project so you can use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)? It’s so much nicer to work with. Said without knowing much about `android.icu.util.Calendar`, but `java.util.Calendar` at least is long outdated and poorly designed, and I don’t get a much better impression of the `icu` one.

Comment: What would the point be? Should your app exploit some ICU feature/s when running on API level 24 and above and thereby present functionality to the user that isn’t available when it runs on API level 23 and lower?

Comment: Or use my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) which offers good internationalization (like ICU4J) AND more calendars in better quality AND compatibility even with old API-levels.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I haven't find any mention of a license, and it is quite strange.

Comment: @OleV.V. Maybe it is a good point. But for what reason android devs have implemented icu.Calendar?
The reasons why I do not want to migrate to ThreeTen:
1. Do not want bloat apk
2. Want to use Android timezone, and not the latest from IANA. I have another app with Jodatime wich gives me lots of pain because of it.

Comment: About Time4A-licence (a derivate from Time4J), see also [this issue](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues/621), Oh, it seems I have forgotten to officially add an extra licence file to the project, sorry for confusion. And about tz-data, the IANA-tzdb is embedded and the default but the platform tz-data can be used, too (although I actually think this could be done in a more comfortable way, for example per initialization parameter).

Answer (score 0):

For using icu.util.Calendar in pre Android 24 you should add the library from IBM into your gradle :

```
implementation group: 'com.ibm.icu', name: 'icu4j', version: '69.1'
```

So instead of using android.icu.util.Calendar you should use com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185965/5945169) help me a lot.

IBM calendar maven : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j