# Persian calendar - Insertion and retrieval date in Persian format from Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, calendar, jalali-calendar

**My application requires the following.**

In my application(in struts), we need to support Persian Calendar.

When we submit a form, date is coming as String in Action class. We need to save this date in Persian format in DB. We have configured DB for Persian Calendar. And while retrieving data from DB user should be able to see the date in Persian format only.

Also, the user can switch in 2 languages(English, Persian). So, application should support both type of calendars(Gregorian and Persian). If user logged-in in English, Gregorian calendar should be visible. If user logged-in in Persian language, then Persian Calendar should be visible.

For date conversion from Gregorian to Persian I am using below:
http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/converter-gregorian-date-jalali-date-20288.aspx

In above requirement, I am facing 2 issues:

1. While submitting a form, how can we save date(which is in String format in Action class) in Persian format in DB?
2. While retrieving data from DB, it should come in Persian format. As of now, the JDBC client is retrieving the date in Gregorian Calender.

I am passing java.sql.Date(today's date) which is getting saved in persian format in DB. Using below code.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = null; 
java.util.Date utilDate = new Date(); 
sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); 
PreparedStatement psmtInsert = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery); 
psmtInsert.setDate(1, sqlDate)); 
psmtInsert.executeUpdate();
```

For retrieving:

```
PreparedStatement psmtSelect = conn.prepareStatement("select dateOfJoining from EMPLOYEE");
ResultSet resultSet = psmtSelect.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getDate(1));
}
```

But it is returning date in Gregorian type.

Do we have any setting in Tomcat/JVM/JDBC client which converts date returned from DB into Persian Format itself(Like we have NLS_CALENDAR ,NLS_DATE_FORMAT in Oracle)?

For 1st issue, if I am passing date in Persian format then In DB it is saving incorrectly. PFB my code:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = null; 
java.util.Date utilDate = new Date("1397/02/04"); 
sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); 
PreparedStatement psmtInsert = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery); 
psmtInsert.setDate(1, sqlDate)); 
psmtInsert.executeUpdate();
```

Above is inserting as 0777/09/13 in DB.

How can we overcome the above issues?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You cannot convert a date from Gregorian to Persian? You know how to do it but you get wrong results? You donÄt know how to converse a date from string to date format? Please narrow down your question, it's too broad now and has no specific problem statement.

Comment: the actual time is universal, why can't u just save the date as  timestamp instead!!! then convert to persian/georgian as required

Comment: @Psytho: Regarding 2nd issue, I am able to save the date in Persian format in DB. But while fetching from DB JDBC client retrieving date in Gregorian format. So, here my question is : Do we have any way using which JDBC client retrieve date in Persian format.

P.S. This is an existing application, so I want minimum changes required to achieve the above. Although, I can convert the date returned from DB to Persian but it will require too much effort. That's why I need some another approach.

Comment: Please add some code how you submit a date to the DB, how you retrieve it from there and how it looks like.

Comment: Please add this code to your question using "Edit" button. Code in the comments is not readable and no one sees it.

Comment: @Psytho : Updated the code in my question. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any library or algorithm for Persian (Shamsi or Jalali) calendar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378764/is-there-any-library-or-algorithm-for-persian-shamsi-or-jalali-calendar-in-and)

Comment: When you say that `new Date("1397/02/04")` (a constructor which is deprecated, BTW) "is inserting as 0777/09/13", how are you determining that? Java appears to have interpreted "1397/02/04" in the Gregorian/Julian calendar (approximately 18078422400000 ms *before* the epoch), which in the "Persian calendar" would be the year 777. If you want Java to interpret "1397/02/04" in some other calendar then you'll need to convert it to Gregorian before storing it, and then convert it back after retrieving it. The code you cited in your question should help with that, assuming that it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> While submitting a form, how can we save date(which is in String format in Action class) in Persian format in DB?

Store the date as a `DATE` data type and when you want to insert it into the table use `TO_DATE` with the NLS calendar parameter for Persian to convert it from a Persion formatted string to a date:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/288)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         '1397/02/05',
         'yyyy/mm/dd',
         'nls_calendar=persian'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/288/0)**:

```
| TO_DATE('1397/02/05','YYYY/MM/DD','NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      2018-04-25T00:00:00Z |
```

> While retrieving data from DB, it should come in Persian format. As of now, the JDBC client is retrieving the date in Gregorian Calender.

When you output the value, just specify the calendar you want to use to format it. So for Persian, use `TO_CHAR` with the NLS calendar parameter for Persian:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         DATE '2018-04-25',
         'yyyy/mm/dd',
         'nls_calendar=persian'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/288/1)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(DATE'2018-04-25','YYYY/MM/DD','NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                    1397/02/05 |
```

> Do we have any way using which JDBC client retrieve date in Persian format.

This is a common misconception. A `DATE` data type stored in Oracle tables as 7 bytes containing year (2 bytes), month, day, hours, minutes and seconds (1 byte each). It does not have any "format" (but it is effectively stored in the Gregorian calendar).

JDBC does not transfer a formatted date, it just transfers those 7 bytes and stores it in a `java.sql.Date` class (which also just stores those bytes).

If you want to format a `DATE` data type then you need to convert it to another data type; typically a string for which you want to use `TO_CHAR` in the Oracle database (or some other method to format Dates in Java).

Comment: yes, above will work. But my problem is that I need to make changes in an existing application. And using above approach I need to make changes in every DAO file which is a very long activity.

Actually, I am looking for some approach in which I need to do minimum changes. 
Some setting in Tomcat/JVM/JDBC client which converts date returned from DB into Persian Format itself(Like we have NLS_CALENDAR ,NLS_DATE_FORMAT in Oracle). Else I'll continue with the suggested approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is no calendar type in `java.sql.Date` so it is impossible to force it to *Persian*. All date/time values in JDBC are normalized in a neutral form and Oracle Database uses a neutral form as well for storage and processing. When `NLS_CALENDAR` is PERSIAN, Oracle converts the value to and from the neutral form and it is just "presenting" it in the Persian calendar convention while it is handling in the neutral form internally.

Usually it is optimal to use a neutral form consistently for all values in the backend. Typically a converter is used in the UI layer as part of the localization to tailor to the preferred locale for individual users. If localization in Java in the middle tier is needed, the `java.time.chrono` package that Douglas is suggesting above would be a clean solution.

Comment: Thanks. This means that the database is sending Persian DATE values to JDBC in Gregorian and that to construct a PersianLocalDate the of method would have to convert from Gregorian. The easiest way to do that is to define of(LocalDate) and use the java.time.chrono support to do the conversion. To send a PersianLocalDate to the database you would use LocalDate.from(TemporalAccessor).

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the inputs for those who still are looking how to implement the Persian calendar in the application.

My application should support Gregorian and Persian calendar, also Oracle and PostgreSQL DBs should be supported.

To implement the Persian calendar with minimum efforts performed the below steps:

1. Converting every date coming from UI into Gregorian format in validate() of form using the implementation suggested in below link
   http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/converter-gregorian-date-jalali-date-20288.aspx
2. Once the dates are converted to Gregorian the whole application will keep running as it was running earlier with Gregorian dates.
3. While saving the date in DB, I decided to store the date in Gregorian format only as I need to support PostgreSQL DB as well and it was not supporting the Persian Calendar.
4. While fetching the data to UI, the date will be retrieved from DB and again I am converting the date in Persian format.

To show the Persian calendar on UI, refer the below link. It has other calendars implementation as well
http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

The above approach can help implementing most of the different calendars.

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Date` is defined to be in UTC which is Gregorian. Getting a DATE from the database as a `java.sql.Date` is not likely to do anything useful. The right answer would be to define a `PersianChronology` which extends `java.time.chrono.AbstractChronology` and `PersianLocalDate` which implements `java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate`. Then get the value from the database as a `PersianLocalDate`. That's a lot of work but it is in theory the right thing to do.

```
PersianLocalDate per = rs.getObject(col, PersianLocalDate.class);
```

I think this could be made to work. Not easy but possible. If your `PersianLocalDate` class defines the following method

```
public static PersianLocalDate of(oracle.sql.DATE date) { ... }
```

then Oracle Database JDBC would use that method to construct a `PersianLocalDate` in the `getObject` call above. The fun part would be implementating the `of(DATE)` method. All of the `oracle.sql.DATE` methods assume a Gregorian calendar. Your best bet is to call `DATE.getBytes` and interpret the bytes yourself. Bytes 0 and 1 are the year, 2 is the month and 3 is the day of the month. `TIMESTAMP.getJavaYear` will convert those two bytes into an int year. It doesn't know anything about calendars; it's just doing arithmetic. Depending on what the database does in sending a Persian DATE as a query result that should let you construct a `PersianLocalDate`. If the database is converting to Gregorian, you'll have to convert back to Persian. Your `PersianChronology` should help with that.

Going the other way, sending a `PersianLocalDate` to the database is going to be more interesting. The Oracle Database JDBC drivers have no capability of converting an unknown class to a database type like DATE, nothing equivalent to the `of` method hook described above. You could try making `PersianLocalDate` extend `oracle.sql.ORAData`. The `toDatum` method would have to return an `oracle.sql.DATE` with the same bytes that the database sent as a query result.

A simpler approach, maybe, would be to send Persian dates back and forth to the database as VARCHARs/Strings. The drivers would call a `static of(String)` method on `PersianLocalDate` so getting a `PersianLocalDate` would be easy. If the database does the right thing with `PersianLocalDate.toString` results then calling setString makes sending the values easy. If not then define `PersianLocalDate.toDatabaseString` and do the conversion yourself.

This is a use case that we talked about when we implemented support for `java.time` but we simply did not have the resources required to do anything. And we didn't know how common it would be so it was hard to justify doing the work. If you have a support contract I'd encourage you to file an SR and ask for an enhancement request. If you can provide a `PersianChronology` and `PersianLocalDate` it would be easier for me to get some resources allocated to do something. Maybe nothing more than a hook to make setObject work, but at least that. I wish I could be more help.