# Scanner vs System.console( ).write( )

Tags: java, string

I tried to print out a string that includes Spanish accents on the screen.
I get different answer with the same input, but with different approaches.

My first approach is to read a string that includes Spanish accents via Scanner class

```
 //input is a á e é i í o ó u ú A Á E É I Í O Ó U Ú Ñ ñ

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter some spanish chars next: ");
    String spanishLine = sc.nextLine();

    try {
        System.out.println("Output from Scanner: " + spanishLine);
        System.console().writer().println(spanishLine);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

My second apporche is which I found from this webiste: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0046.html

```
        String s = "a á e é i í o ó u ú A Á E É I Í O Ó U Ú Ñ ñ";

        try {
            System.out.println("Output from System.console: " + s);
            System.console().writer().println(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

My out come is as follows

```
Enter some spanish chars next: 
a á e é i í o ó u ú A Á E É I Í O Ó U Ú Ñ ñ
output from Scanner: a � e � i � o � u � A � E � I � O � U � � �
output from System.console: a á e é i í o ó u ú A Á E É I Í O Ó U Ú Ñ ñ
```

Can anyone explain why I get two different answers from the same input.
How can I fix up my first approach to have same result as the second one?

Comment: Both are using different output streams, and having different encodings.

Comment: what you mean? could you please be more clear?

Comment: Where are you testing this application?

Comment: Try to set encoding manually.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza in netbeans 8

Comment: @user979349 I did everything, but my question is why second works and why first doesn't?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan In both cases he is using `System.console().writer().println`

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood : Hey, You misundertood the question, OP has a different answer while writing to `Sout` and `console`. Reason is both are different steams and having different encodings

Comment: use Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() on your machine and if it is other than spanish. then this is System locale issue.

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev sorry no clue how to use this. should I setup spanish font?

Comment: @KickButtowski - You need to change to spanish locale; not font, Use this http://java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev I followed what you said, and it did not work

Comment: -1. Your "outcome" here doesn't match either your first program or your second program.  How can anyone understand what you're asking if you provide output that's different from what you're actually getting?  Please try get your question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Not an answer***

You still need to check some things.

1. The java source encoding used by the java compiler must be the same as the encoding of the text/editor.

   - You can check this with a programmer's editor like JEdit or NotePad++.
2. Check the default encoding:

   - `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`
   - Or add an extra encoding parameter to the Scanner constructor
   - The reason being, that often there is a method/constructor version without encoding where the default platform encoding is taken.
3. Redirect the System.out/console to a file.

   - In this case it suffices to write the string to UTF-8.
4. **Try the real console**, not that of the IDE.

   - The encoding of the IDE "console" may be configurable.

I find the behaviour puzzling. It would look as if the Scanner took a charset encoding UTF-8 and then had to write it to US-ASCII, so umappable characters are given by `�`. That cannot be. It looks like Scanner would be "buggy" - which I doubt.

Try dump the string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
    int cp = s.codePointAt(i);
    System.out.printf(" %x", cp);
    i += Character.charCount(cp);
}
System.out.println();
```

---

***(Normally not done)***

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding","Windows-1252");
```

Comment: could you show me a tutorial how to change encoding inside file.encoding? mine is UTF-8 , and I want to switch it to ISO

Comment: Extended the answer; Windows-1252 aka Cp1252 (Windows Latin-1) is a superset of ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) which covers Spanish.

Comment: what is the normal way?

Comment: Normal is (1) not to use the console, certainly not the IDE console, and always use an explicit encoding parameter. Or (2) when using the console relying on the default platform encoding.However in your case something is fishy. I have Linux with an UTF-8 console, and I am almost inclined, you have something alike, maybe with a US-ASCII locale for the keyboard or something else incomprehensible.

Comment: K your answers are much clear than others. thank you. yet how can I be sure that my program does not end up with this kind of issue at all?
how can I inject some codes that cover all langues with their accents?
this is my last question before voting you. please if you find my question interesting, vote me too.

Answer (score 3):

using the second method, the bytes of the String are input directly into the app.  Using the first method, you are relying upon the Locale of the Scanner

see 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)

Comment: so if I change Locale of scanner to Spanish, I am going to get the same result? or I did not understand your answer? 
If I did not , could you please provide more explanation, tutorial, or a sample plz?

Comment: `I am going to get the same result?` - Yes

Comment: sc.useLocale(Locale.?); I use this but there is no locale for spanish?am i using the right line of code?

Comment: it is k. I wanna learn this. can you help to solve it?could you tell me why you misred this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54588/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-i-wish-i-could-think-of-a-good).

Comment: I thought that the problem was between approach1 and approach2.  Does `System.out.println("Output from System.console: " + s.getBytes ("es_ES"));` work