# Java international characters not recognized when compiled

Tags: java, netbeans, character, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse html documents in a project i created in Netbeans. The html pages i parse are in Greek, UTF-8, and i have to identify some elements that contain specific Greek strings. This works well when i test the program in Netbeans:

```
Element element = record.select("td:containsOwn(διαθέσιμο)").first();
```

However, when I build a jar file and run it from the windows 7 command prompt, the program fails to find the element with the greek characters!

Netbeans encoding is set to UTF-8.
I am using JRE 1.7.0 when i run from the cmd.
Netbeans is using JDK 1.7

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why would it matter what encoding is used by the command prompt?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP said "the program fails to find the element", not "it prints incorrectly".

Comment: @loannis tsiokos , please take a look at my posts ; might give you some idea.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902098/accent-%EF%BF%BD-in-netbeans/23902863#23902863

Comment: next post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904391/why-different-answer-from-same-string

Comment: @shmosel I did misread that.

Comment: if i try to print the greek string in windows cmd, it also prints incorrectly; whereas in Netbeans it prints with the correct characters. Any other ideas? @KickButtowski

Comment: may be you don't have the proper font