# Java difference between running from netbeans and cmd

Tags: java, jar, cmd, runtime

I have a program that writes text data to files. When I run it from netbeans the files are in a correct encoding and you can read them with a notepad. When I run it from cmd using `java -cp ....jar` the encoding is different.

What may be the issue??

ps. I've checked that the jre. versions are the same that executes (v 1.8.0_31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans startup scripts may specify a different encoding than your system default. You can check in your netbeans.conf.

You can set the `file.encoding` property when invoking `java`. For example, `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -cp... jar`.

If you do not want to be surprised when running your code on different environments, even better solution would be to specify the encoding in your source code.

Further reading:

- file encoding: [Character and Byte Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html)
- netbeans.conf encoding options: [How To Display UTF8 In Netbeans 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922845/how-to-display-utf8-in-netbeans-7)

Comment: How you specify the encoding in the source? And why the default jvm encoding is different. Netbeans sets it explicitly?